# How to Assign a XAML Stype from Common/StandardStyles.xaml in code behind

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, styles

I have search and tried a number of things to do this.  I have a style that is successfully bound to multiple XAML frames by doing XAML code like this, the name of the style is ViewPersonTextboxDataStyle:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Name="textboxName" Text="{Binding textboxName}" Margin="5,5,5,5" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextboxDataStyle}"/>
```

So, when I get to another frame where I want to create the Grid rows and definitions in a code behind, I tried this, which I thought was correct:

```
var resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary()
{
    Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Common/StandardStyles.xaml", UriKind.Absolute)
};
var style = resourceDictionary["ViewPersonTextboxDataStyle"] as Style;
textBlock.Style = resourceDictionary["ViewPersonTextboxDataStyle"] as Style;
```

So at this point, I can see the style was found in the resource dictionary as style is populated correctly.  But assigning into textBlock.Style causes a Catastrophic Exception.  So, either I am missing a step or this is incorrect.

Not alot of net information on this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thank you Raghavendra, this did point me in the right direction to tell me that things I was trying weren't off base.

What I ended up with is:

```
style = Application.Current.Resources["ViewPersonTextDataStyle"] as Style;
textBlock.Style = style;
```

Raghavendra is right, you don't need to use resource manager, and you also don't need to define it in the local XAML.  I used the above line to do it by assigning current in every one of my frames anyway.

So with that, my exception was one for an IDIOT (namely me).  I should have been using my TEXTBLOCK style not my TEXTBOX style.  Assigning a textbox style to the textblock was causing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textBlock.style = this.Resources["ViewPersonTextboxDataStyle"] as Style;
```

You need not use ResourceDictionary

**Edit:**

this.Resources refers to Page.Resources (that is in case the ViewPersonTextboxDataStyle is defined in Page.Resources we use this)

Try this one:

```
    textBlock.style = App.Current.Resources["ViewPersonTextboxDataStyle"] as Style;
```

Comment: That still gives [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException] = {"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."}

Comment: And actually that is because this.Resources has no keys.

Comment: Now this gives {"Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))"} System.Exception